# javax.validation Constraint, adding a violation to a property of a property

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations, hibernate-annotations

Im trying to use a custom javax.validation Constraint annotation in order to set a violation of one of the fields held on the declaring objects field.

For instance I have a car object

```
@MyConstraint
class Car { 
    public int people; 
    public Driver driver;
}

class Driver { 
    public String licenseType;
}
```

Now i need my constraint to set an error on the licenseType field of driver with a custom message based on the number of people in the car. For instance, it could validate that if there is over 2 people are in the car and that the license type must be "Expert" , then set the violation on the driver licenseType, saying this must be a license type of "Expert" as the constraint violation message.

Currently im trying to do this in the annotations validation class:

```
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    context
        .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("my custom message")
        .addPropertyNode("driver.licenseType")
        .addConstraintViolation();
```

Does anyone know if what im trying to do is achievable ?